# How to run Java using Sublime Text 3 on Mac OS

Tags: java, sublimetext3

Recently, I have got to know Sublime Text 3, and tried to run Java in it.

I have modified JavaC.sublime-build in the package, Java.sublime-package.

JavaC.sublime-build:

```
{
    "cmd": ["runJava.sh", "$file_base_name"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

I have shell script(runJava.sh) as below, and I put it in the Java bin folder.

runJava.sh:

```
[ -f "$1.class" ] && rm $1.class
for file in $1.java
do
echo "Compiling $file........"
javac $file
done
if [ -f "$1.class" ]
then
echo "-----------OUTPUT-----------"
java $1
else
echo " "
fi
```

Java bin folder:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
```

However, when I build a java file, I got an error message saying that....

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'runJava.sh'
[cmd: ['runJava.sh', 'Test']]
[dir: /Users/xxxxxxx/Desktop]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

I have no idea why this message showed up, because runJava.sh is located in the right place, which is the Java bin folder.

What is the reason of this problem?

Answer (score 15):

Easy step-by-step:

1. Install [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) if you have't already
2. Using Package Control, install [Package Resource Viewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer)
3. Open Package Control, type `prv` and run `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`
4. Select `Java`
5. Select `JavaC.sublime-build`
6. Replace the build JSON definition with the below code block exactly
7. You're done! `ctrl+b` should now compile and run your Java file.

Build JSON definition:

```
{
  "cmd": ["javac \"$file_name\" && java \"$file_base_name\""],
  "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.java",
  "shell": true
}
```

Answer (score 12):

That's because you are not supposed to modify package files directly with an editor. They are zip files, despite they don't have an extension to warn the user.

To modify the plug-in you have to go to /Packages and unzip the Java.sublime-package file. I'll use linux syntax but the procedure remains the same:

```
cd <sublime-text3-folder>/Packages
mkdir java
cp Java.sublime-packages java
cd java
unzip Java.sublime-packages
```

Then use an editor to modify JavaC.sublime-build to add the following lines (don' forget the extra comma after the last line

```
{
   "shell_cmd": "javac \"$file\"",
   "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.java",

   "variants":
   [
       {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell_cmd": "java $file_base_name"
       }
   ]
}
```

Zip again the contents in Java.sublime-package and put it back in Package folder via:

> zip Java.sublime-package * cp Java.sublime-package
>   ..//Packages

Restart sublime and now along with Ctrl+B to build your project you will be able to run it with Ctrl + Mayus + B

Comment: I created a new build system using Tools > Build System > New Build System > and pasted the script into untitled.sublime-build. Then saved it as java.sublime-build and saved it under at <user_home>./config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User. Now, it shows up as a build system under Tools > Build System and Ctrl + B compiles and Ctrl + Shift + B run the java programs.

Comment: after setting this up, make sure you press `Ctrl + Shift + B` to run `JavaC` again. Then, assuming it successfully built, press it again, this time choosing `JavaC Run`. From here on out simply press `Ctrl + B` to run.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the setting as below,  so that  we are able to build & run java file  with a single type (Command + B)


{
   "cmd": ["java", "$file_base_name"],
 "file_regex": "^ *\\[javac\\] (.+):([0-9]+):() (.*)$",
 "selector": "source.java"
}

Answer (score 9):

There are many solutions out there that kind of say the same thing without providing a step-by-step. So here was my experience on a Mac'16 with **Sublime Text 3**:

Open a terminal window and do the following:

> $ cd /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages/

Made a temp directory to mess with.

> $ mkdir java

Copy current **Java.sublime-package** into new *java* directory and *cd* into *java*.

> $ cp Java.sublime-package java/
>
> $ cd java

Then, unzip the package to see the contents:

> $ unzip Java.sublime-package

Now, edit the build file, **JavaC.sublime-build**. If you have sublime text's command line script:

> $ subl JavaC.sublime-build

Otherwise,

> $ vi JavaC.sublime-build

Then I copied the following into my **JavaC.sublime-build** which I found here posted by [Sean Mullen](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-compile-and-run-Java-in-Sublime-Text-2):

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac \"$file_name\" && java \"$file_base_name\""],
    "shell": true,
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

After that, save, and while inside the *java* directory type:

> $ zip Java.sublime-package *

Move new build package to necessary folder (parent directory):

> $ mv Java.sublime-package ../

UPDATE: 4/18/18:
Sorry it took me so long to adjust this answer. Based on comments from @bumbu, we do need to execute the following command before removing the temp directory:

> $ cd ..

Remove temp *java* directory:

> $ rm -fr java/

And DONE. Now building the Java file will now attempt to run it as well. I prefer this behavior instead of having to do another "variant" to run the program.

Comment: You have to do `cd ..` before removing temporary java folder

Comment: Great answer, very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In Sublime Text 3, you just need simply click **tools -> Build System -> New Build System**  and then paste the following from [Sean Mullen](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-compile-and-run-Java-in-Sublime-Text-2):

```
{
"cmd": ["javac \"$file_name\" && java \"$file_base_name\""],
"shell": true,
"file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.java"
}
```

Then Save it as **java_run.sublime-build**

That's it! When you click **tools -> Build System** again, you'll see java_run, choose this and then try to build, the java file will be compiled and run automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I modified mine to be as this

to run you do ctrl + shift + b

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "javac \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell_cmd": "java $file_base_name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin` is not in Sublime's path, as indicated by your error message. There are two ways to get around this. The first is to either move `runJava.sh` to `/usr/bin`, or create a symlink to it there. The second is to alter your `JavaC.sublime-build` file like so:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["runJava.sh", "$file_base_name"],
    "path": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:$PATH",
    "shell": true,
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

This adds your Java `bin` folder to Sublime's `PATH` when the build system is executing, so that it can find `runJava.sh`. Adding `"shell": true` runs the command through bash, which will allow it to pick up your other environment variables.

Comment: Test: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/runJava.sh: Permission denied
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 126]
[cmd: ['runJava.sh', 'Test']]
[dir: /Users/xxxxx/Desktop]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but there are another error message came up as above. Permission denied.. What am I supposed do?